# Report Viewer with httpOnlyCookies

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer, httpcookie

Is there a way for me to have `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />` in my web.config and still be able to user Report Viewer?

From what I can Google/Bing this doesn't seem possible as Report Viewer must try to access a cookie via javascript.

My only work around so far is to have all the report*.aspx pages in a sub directory with its own config to set `httpOnlyCookies=false`.

Maybe there is some way I can tell Report Viewer not to use cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase someone else randomly searches for this, ReportViewer works fine with `httpOnlyCookies=true`.

I discovered my issue was with not accessing the page via SSL. Wish I would of noticed that obvious mistake earlier.